# thread c++ linux

Tags: c++, linux, c

Всем привет.
Прошу помощи.

**Задание:**

> Задается число - threads. Главная нить создает threads нитей, каждая из которых печатает "hello world". После того, как эти нити завершатся, главная нить печатает "goodbye world".
>   Используемые функции: pthread_create; pthread_exit; pthread_join

Мой код:

```
void *print_hello_world(void *tid)
{
    printf("Hello world %d\n", tid);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main(void)
{

int a;
int i;
int status;
cin >> a;
pthread_t threads[a];

for (i = 1; i <= a; i++)
{

    status = pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, print_hello_world, (void *)i);

    if (status != 0)
    {
        printf("Error %d\n", status);
        exit(-1);
    }
}
printf ("goodbye")
exit(NULL);
}
```

На выходе:

> Hello world 3
>
> Hello world 1
>
> goodbyeHello world 4
>
> Hello world 5
>
> Hello world 2

Я не могу понять где здесь можно реализовать "pthread_join" и почему такая беда с выводом.

Comment: [Там есть пример кода](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так как вы не ожидаете завершения потока , вывод может быть в любой последовательности, но если подождать завершения то вывод будет последовательный

```
 for (i = 1; i <= a; i++)
{

    status = pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, print_hello_world, (void *)i);

    if (status != 0)
    {
        printf("Error %d\n", status);
        exit(-1);
    }
    pthread_join(threads[i],NULL);

}
```

Comment: Спасибо. Теперь вывод в нужном порядке.